# String concatenation is not happening in JS SpiderMonkey

Tags: javascript, hex, ascii, nashorn, spidermonkey

I have a deployment environment where I am running my JS codes in SpiderMonkey JS engine.

I had to do some conversion from HEX to ASCII.
I am iterating through a HEX string and concatenating to a string variable.
This code can work in Nashorn Engine but it could not work in SpiderMonkey

```
function hextoascii(str1)
{
    var hex  = str1.toString();
    var str = '';
    var substr = '';
    var parsedInt = 0;
    for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) 
    {
        substr = hex.substr(n, 2);
        parsedInt = parseInt(substr, 16);
        str = '' + str.concat(String.fromCharCode(parsedInt));          
        log.info("n: " + n + " - parsedInt: " + parsedInt + " str: " + str);
    }
    return str;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
n: 0 - parsedInt: 77 str: M
n: 2 - parsedInt: 90 str: MZ
n: 4 - parsedInt: 144 str: MZ
n: 6 - parsedInt: 0 str: MZ
n: 8 - parsedInt: 3 str: MZ
```

How to fix my concatenation?

Comment: Character codes 144, 0, and 3 are for control codes and won't be visible. What is it that you expected?

Comment: Also you don't have to use `.concat()`, you can use `str += String.fromCharCode(parsedInt)`

Comment: So Should I just discard 144, 0 and 3?

Comment: Well you said the code worked on Nashorn; what made you feel like that got a correct answer while this one is incorrect?

Comment: Because our Unit Test framework works in Nashorn. When I call the same method in the Nashorn engine the log is displayed and the string is getting longer after each iteration. But in the SpiderMonkey engine it does not works. SpiderMonkey engine, I am not sure which version it is.

Comment: The control codes are converted to something but I want them in my text at the end.

Comment: How do you know they're not in the text? You can't see them, by definition. Add `str.length` to your `console.log()` statement.

Comment: When I run the code in Node, the characters are definitely all being appended.

Comment: I know because the there are actually more hex text to be converted which are different than 144, 3 and 0. I tried by discarding these 3 numbers it was able to append the rest. So I guess it has an issue with those 3 numbers. I guess when I concatanate the characters it those 3 numbers may be changing the type of my variable other than string. But I really appreciate your efforts to find a solution :)

Comment: No, those characters are not changing the type of your variable; it is still a string.